# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven .plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.22.0:

Tags: maven

I am facing an issue with my maven `pom.xml` file.

Dependency for maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0 is returning error

> “Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven
>   .plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.22.0”

Below is my pom.xml file

I have also tried with below setting and still, it’s not working.

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployments -> Maven Check the box, ‘Always update snapshots’

Answer (score 0):

From your error message there seems to be a space to much.

try

```
org.apache.maven.plugins
```

instead of

```
org.apache.maven .plugins
```

in your pom